Likelihood function of paired conditional logistic regression
I found the information about the likelihood of conditional logistic regression for paired data is few. The Wiki gives this answer, but I think it is wrong because event Yi1 and Yi2 are dependent, because Yi1 + Yi2 =1. (Yi is a binary random variable). Therefore, how do we solve the conditional likelihood based on the assumption of Yi1 + Yi2 = 1? I have not found any proof yet. Thanks.

Updated on 10May2024
This is my calculation.


No, Wikipedia is correct.  $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are dependent, but they are dependent only after conditioning on $Y_1+Y_2=1$.  You start with $Y_{i1}$ and $Y_{i2}$ independent Bernoulli with $Y_{ij}$ having mean $\mathrm{expit}(\alpha_i+X_{ij}\beta)$ in the population.
At this point you either sample in such a way that $Y_{i1}+Y_{i2}=1$ (matched case-control sampling) or you sample pairs without regard to $Y$ and condition on $Y_{i1}+Y_{i2}=1$ in the analysis (because pairs where that isn't true aren't informative for $\beta$)
Either way, the conditional likelihood for pair $i$ is $P(Y_{i1}=1|Y_{i1}+Y_{i2}=1;\beta)$ or $P(Y_{i1}=0|Y_{i1}+Y_{i2}=1;\beta)$

Hello, Thomas. Thank you for your reply. However, I do not quite understand the proof. I drew a flow of my understanding.

You're still treating $A$ and $B$ as dependent. They are independent Bernoulli prior to conditioning, so that eg $P(A=0|B=1)$ is just $P(A=0)$

Hi, Thomas. Oh! I got your point. Hmmm, without the conditioning of A + B = 1, there should not have been the correlation between A and B. Thank you very much, pal.

Hi, Thomas. Here I have another question. We know that P(A and B) = P(A | B)*P(B) holds true regardless of the status of the correlation between A and B. When we compute P(A and B), how should we determine whether to treat it as independent between A and B, or to treat them as P(A and B) = P(A | B)*P(B). Thx
